# HTML5 canvas in MS Edge always saves as PNG. How can I make it JPG?

Tags: html, image, canvas, microsoft-edge, todataurl

Here is my code...

```
<img id="imgsave" />

$("#imgsave").attr("src",canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1.0));
```

I'm writing the toDataURL output to an html image and setting it as jpeg. But when I right click the image and try to save it, it's always PNG whatever I do. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to convert the jpg dataURL to a Blob. You need to convert the dataURL to a string with `str = atob(dataURL)` then put that string into a `Uint8Array`  as follows `dat = new Uint8Array(str.length);i=0;while(i <str.length){dat[i] = str.charCodeAt(i++)&0xFF;};` then `blob=new Blob(dat,{type :"image/jpeg"})` then `navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,"filename.jpg");` I think that should do it.

Comment: Really, all that work? I was hoping that the Edge browser just needed slightly different syntax to save as jpg. Why would a modern browser ignore the jpg setting? I appreciate your help though.

Comment: I was surprised as well. In Fact you pointed me to a bug in my code I was not aware was there. I was using `navigator.msSaveBlob(canvas.msToBlob(),name+"."+type);` with type being "jpg" and it saved the image with the jpg extension. But file content showed it as png. I did not post last coment as answer as I have actually yet to try and see if it works.

Comment: @Kaiido  if there is a canvas.toBlob on edge then they have hidden it well at MSDN as I can not find a referance to a canvas version. canvas.msToBlob works on Edge but will only encode to bmp, or jpg.

Comment: [1/2] @Blindman67, it seems you are right, I misread MDN page... Still, I think the [toBlob polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Polyfill) is simply easier, and won't loose too much performances against the synchronous MS version. But anyway, after opening my VM, it seems OP's problem is not related to the canvas actually, it's any image with a `data:image/xxx` uri scheme that will only be savable in either png or bmp when right click "save As..." I tried with a FileReader and the same occurs.

Comment: [2/2] Even setting the img's src to a BlobURL will do the same (directly from an XHR's Blob response which is correctly saved as jpg with `msSaveBlob`). Your solution would allow to save the file as jpg, but it would also require overwriting the contextmenu... One should probably just write a bug report to MS.